# Nginx+uwsgi not serving Django application

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm following this tutorial: https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

When I get to this point: https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#nginx-and-uwsgi-and-test-py
things stop working as they should.

http://example.com:8000/ returns nothing, and the nginx error log is empty. What am I doing wrong?

my ssite_nginx.conf is as follows:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    #server unix:///home/ubuntu/ssite/ssite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/ssite/ssite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend $
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/ssite/ssite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend$
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/ssite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Comment: And are you running uwsgi? How is that configured/started?

Comment: I haven't gotten to the point where I need to configure uwsgi with .ini file as yet (according to the tutorial). I have the uwsgi_params file from here https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params at /home/ubuntu/ssite/uwsgi_params. uwsgi is started with sudo service uwsgi start

Comment: But that is not what that part of the tutorial says. It says to start it with `uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py`, so that it listens on port 8001.

Comment: Sorry, I got your question wrong. I am doing exactly that, starting with uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py.

Comment: It says: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 13529, cores: 1) and http://example.com:8000/  says webpage not available.

Comment: example.com is just an example domain, try your_ip:8000

Comment: @itzmeontv: I'm aware of that, I'm using my own ip only for ip:8000.

Comment: is configuring this in a remote server or local ?

Comment: This is on a remote aws ec2 server.

Comment: Did you solve this somehow?